# MariaDB 10.4 fine tuning for a large number of queries

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mariadb-10.4

I have a server with such parameters:

```
OS: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS x86_64
Kernel: 4.15.0-112-generic
CPU: Intel Xeon Silver 4214 (48 Cores) @ 2.201GHz
Memory: 96Gb
SSD SAMSUNG MZQLB960HAJR-00007 894.3Gb x 2
```

With installed `5.5.5-10.4.12-MariaDB-1:10.4.12+maria~bionic`. I have a PHP written project with pretty high number of DB queries (~400-500 SELECTs per second + ~200-300 UPDATEs per second). The problem is: the database is rather slow during a lot of users activity, but ok in any other time. My `my.cfg` file is below:

```
# this is read by the standalone daemon and embedded servers
[server]

# this is only for the mysqld standalone daemon
[mysqld]

#
# * Basic Settings
#
user = mysql
pid-file = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port = 3306
basedir = /usr
datadir = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
skip-name-resolve
max_connections = 1000000
bind-address = 0.0.0.0

#
# * Fine Tuning
#
key_buffer_size = 96M
max_allowed_packet = 16M
thread_stack = 192K
thread_cache_size = 32

# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam-recover         = BACKUP

lock_wait_timeout = 10
interactive_timeout = 10
wait_timeout = 3

#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
query_cache_type = 0
query_cache_limit = 0
query_cache_size = 0
open-files-limit = 320000
thread_cache_size = 64

#
# * Logging and Replication
#
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
expire_logs_days = 10
max_binlog_size = 100M

#
# * InnoDB
#

innodb_buffer_pool_size = 10000M
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 128
max_heap_table_size = 1000M
tmp_table_size = 1000M
sort_buffer_size = 96M
innodb_sort_buffer_size = 96M
read_buffer_size = 96M

#
# * Character sets
#
character-set-server  = utf8mb4
collation-server      = utf8mb4_general_ci


# this is only for embedded server
[embedded]

[mariadb]
max_statement_time = 15
thread_handling = pool-of-threads
thread_pool_size = 48
```

Recently I've changed `thread_handling = pool-of-threads` and `wait_timeout = 3`: it gave some performance boost, but didn't solve the problem in general. I'll be grateful for any ideas how to speed up it or eliminate some "bottlenecks".

**UPDATE:**

> Use InnoDB, not MyISAM

It's already so.

> Turn on the slowlog to find the slowest queries.

Well, all of my SELECTs calls only one table (~500k records, without JOINs and/or subqueries), and mostly of them have LIMIT 1, so not so large amount of data.

> Let's see SHOW CREATE TABLE.

Ok, here is `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for this main table:

```
CREATE TABLE `orders` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `order_created_datetime` timestamp NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `order_updated_datetime` timestamp NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ON UPDATE current_timestamp(),
  `order_last_perform_datetime` timestamp NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `order_category_id` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `order_url` text CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `order_social_shortcode` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `order_social_id` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `order_title` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `order_preview_pic` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `order_custom_data` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `order_price_usd` decimal(13,6) DEFAULT 0.000000,
  `order_daily_limit` int(11) DEFAULT 0,
  `order_hourly_limit` int(11) DEFAULT 0,
  `order_minute_limit` int(11) DEFAULT 0,
  `order_overall_limit` int(11) DEFAULT 0,
  `order_initial_social_counter` int(11) DEFAULT 0,
  `order_daily_counter` int(11) DEFAULT 0,
  `order_hourly_counter` int(11) DEFAULT 0,
  `order_minute_counter` int(11) DEFAULT 0,
  `order_overall_counter` int(11) DEFAULT 0,
  `order_allowed_countries` text CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `order_forbidden_countries` text CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `order_api` tinyint(4) DEFAULT 0,
  `order_reported` tinyint(4) DEFAULT 0,
  `order_active` tinyint(4) DEFAULT 1,
  `order_deleted` tinyint(4) DEFAULT 0,
  `order_deleted_datetime` timestamp NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `order_deleted_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `users_log_actions` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `users_log_hidden` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `index_user_id` (`user_id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `index_order_category_id` (`order_category_id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `index_order_deleted` (`order_deleted`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `index_order_active` (`order_active`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `index_order_social_id` (`order_social_id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `index_users_log_actions` (`users_log_actions`(1024)) USING BTREE,
  KEY `index_users_log_hidden` (`users_log_hidden`(1024)) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=461811 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC
```

> innodb_buffer_pool_size may be too small -- How much data do you have? How much RAM is available to MariaDB?

Well, MariaDB run on a standalone server, without any other software (PHP, Apache, etc). So I have 96Gb RAM on this server and all of these can be used by MariaDB.

> innodb_buffer_pool_instances is too large; it should be  - buffer_pool_size/1G

Could you please clarify this? In my case it should be buffer_pool_size/96Gb, or? I think `buffer_pool_size` have its default value in my configuration.

> What is the value if innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit?

It's `1`, but I tried `2` with no result.

Comment: Please post your slow query and last 400 lines of your SLOW QUERY LOG, if available.

Comment: Additional information request. From your MySQL Host server. Post on pastebin.com and share the links. From your SSH login root, Text results of: B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; after minimum 24 hours UPTIME C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; E) complete MySQLTuner report AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - htop OR top for most active apps, ulimit -a for a Linux/Unix list of limits, iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Please consider posting Additional information requested on Sep 16 at 20:26 to suggestions to improve your my.cnf utilization of available RAM.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using innodb so need to tweak few innodb parameters in first go.

**innodb_buffer_pool_size** is too small as You have 96 GB of RAM. Can give 50% atleast to this variables and reduce **innodb_buffer_pool_instances** as well.

If you can afford 1-2 second data loss then set value of **innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit** to 2.

Set **max_allowed_packet** to 256 M

Reduce **max_connections** to 1000

Set **tmp_table_size** to 256M

Set **sql_binlog** and **innodb_doublewrite** to 0

NOTE: *SELECT ( @@key_buffer_size + @@query_cache_size + @@innodb_buffer_pool_size + @@innodb_log_buffer_size + @@max_connections * ( @@read_buffer_size + @@read_rnd_buffer_size + @@sort_buffer_size + @@join_buffer_size + @@binlog_cache_size + @@thread_stack + @@tmp_table_size )) / (1024 * 1024 * 1024) AS MAX_MEMORY_GB;* should be less than 80% of total RAM.

Comment: I've changed these variables as you suggested, and this query shows 504GB for some reason. `key_buffer_size=100663296` `query_cache_size=0` `innodb_buffer_pool_size=68719476736` `innodb_log_buffer_size=16777216` `max_connections=1000` `read_buffer_size=100663296` `read_rnd_buffer_size=262144` `sort_buffer_size=100663296` `join_buffer_size=262144` `binlog_cache_size=32768` `thread_stack=196608` `tmp_table_size=268435456`

Comment: Btw, I have no any issues with memory, but CPUs are almost always overloaded.

Comment: if we don't have enough memory then queries will read from disk and if disk is not performing well then will do for IO wait. 

Also recommending to capture slow queries.

Comment: @VickyPopovic Please post additional information requested on 9/16/2020 at 20:08.

Comment: Note: recent versions of MariaDB have deprecated `innodb_buffer_pool_instances`, so there is no point in setting it any more.